# how to import data into pg_statistic table?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to export statistics of a table and want to put the same stats without data into another table. But it throws error "cannot accept a value of type anyarray" - is it possible to import stats via this or any other way in postgres?

```
edb=# copy (select * from pg_statistic where starelid in (select oid from pg_class where relname in ('t'))) to stdout with delimiter ',';
16446,1,f,0,4,-1,2,3,0,0,0,97,97,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\N,{0.994006},\N,\N,\N,{1\,10\,20\,30\,40\,50\,60\,70\,80\,90\,100\,110\,120\,130\,140\,150\,160\,170\,180\,190\,200\,210\,220\,230\,240\,250\,260\,270\,280\,290\,300\,310\,320\,330\,340\,350\,360\,370\,380\,390\,400\,410\,420\,430\,440\,450\,460\,470\,480\,490\,500\,510\,520\,530\,540\,550\,560\,570\,580\,590\,600\,610\,620\,630\,640\,650\,660\,670\,680\,690\,700\,710\,720\,730\,740\,750\,760\,770\,780\,790\,800\,810\,820\,830\,840\,850\,860\,870\,880\,890\,900\,910\,920\,930\,940\,950\,960\,970\,980\,990\,1000},\N,\N,\N,\N
16446,2,f,0,4,-0.999,1,2,3,0,0,96,97,97,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,{0.002},\N,{0.99402994},\N,\N,{3},{2\,12\,22\,32\,42\,52\,62\,72\,82\,92\,102\,112\,122\,132\,142\,152\,162\,172\,182\,192\,202\,212\,222\,232\,242\,252\,262\,272\,282\,292\,302\,312\,322\,332\,341\,351\,361\,371\,381\,391\,401\,411\,421\,431\,441\,451\,461\,471\,481\,491\,501\,511\,521\,531\,541\,551\,561\,571\,581\,591\,601\,611\,621\,631\,641\,651\,661\,670\,680\,690\,700\,710\,720\,730\,740\,750\,760\,770\,780\,790\,800\,810\,820\,830\,840\,850\,860\,870\,880\,890\,900\,910\,920\,930\,940\,950\,960\,970\,980\,990\,1000},\N,\N,\N

-- trying to create a copy of pg_statistics table
edb=# create table pg_statistic_test as select * from pg_statistic where 1=2;
ERROR:  column "stavalues1" has pseudo-type anyarray

edb=# copy pg_catalog.pg_statistic from '/tmp/pg_statistics.txt' with delimiter ',';
ERROR:  cannot accept a value of type anyarray
CONTEXT:  COPY pg_statistic, line 1, column stavalues1: "{1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250,260,27..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot transfer table statistics from one database to another. There is no support for that. It has been discussed in the context of upgrades, but the onus of supporting different versions seems to outweigh the usefulness.

Comment: ok, thanks...yeah I saw the same in older forums for upgrades, asked to see if something has changed and if there was support with latest versions.